# Draw Text within DrawScope - Jetpack Compose Desktop

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, skia, compose-desktop

**I want to draw Text inside a canvas to display a label for a chart.**

On Android, I can use the library: https://github.com/tehras/charts (For Compose: 1-alpha03)
but on Desktop I can't.

Thus I tried to rewrite the broken parts.
But I can't get the labels to display.

Original Code, which I try to change to work with Desktop [Source](https://github.com/tehras/charts/blob/master/lib/line/src/main/java/com/github/tehras/charts/line/renderer/yaxis/SimpleYAxisDrawer.kt):

```kotlin
    private val textPaint = android.graphics.Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        color = labelTextColor.toLegacyInt()
    }
    private val textBounds = android.graphics.Rect()

    override fun drawAxisLabels(
        drawScope: DrawScope,
        canvas: Canvas,
        drawableArea: Rect,
        minValue: Float,
        maxValue: Float
    ) = with(drawScope) {
        val labelPaint = textPaint.apply {
            textSize = labelTextSize.toPx()
            textAlign = android.graphics.Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }
        val minLabelHeight = (labelTextSize.toPx() * labelRatio.toFloat())
        val totalHeight = drawableArea.height
        val labelCount = max((drawableArea.height / minLabelHeight).roundToInt(), 2)

        for (i in 0..labelCount) {
            val value = minValue + (i * ((maxValue - minValue) / labelCount))

            val label = labelValueFormatter(value)
            val x = drawableArea.right - axisLineThickness.toPx() - (labelTextSize.toPx() / 2f)

            labelPaint.getTextBounds(label, 0, label.length, textBounds)

            val y = drawableArea.bottom - (i * (totalHeight / labelCount)) + (textBounds.height() / 2f)

            canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText(label, x, y, labelPaint)
        }
    }
```

For me, the function at the end `NativeCanvas::drawText` does not exist on Compose Desktop. I tried to replace all the logic with a TextPainter but nothing was painted.

What could I try to make it work ? or 
Are there dependencies I could import from Android to just make it work?

COMPOSE_DESKTOP_VERSION: "0.3.0-build138"
KOTLIN_VERSION: "1.4.21"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Desktop Compose native canvas should have a couple of methods related to drawing text. Instead of `canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText`, you could try calling `canvas.nativeCanvas.drawString(label, x, y, org.jetbrains.skija.Font(), labelPaint)`.

I got this using version `0.4.0-build177` of Desktop Compose, so YMMV on different versions.

This also comes with a few caveats:

- If you want to style the text (other than color), you'll have to construct your own `Font` instance. The empty constructor seems to use some system defaults. I'm still learning the API myself, so I would suggest reading through the documentation (which at the moment is just the [code](https://github.com/JetBrains/skija/blob/bb82da2cb938d037dab05756cb6f7053670d2cae/shared/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/skija/Font.java), I think).
- You might also need to change how you create the `Paint` since (at least on the version I was using) doesn't support `textSize` on the `Paint` - I had to specify this as part of the `Font` creation.
- It seems to assume left alignment. A way that I found to get it to work was to use `TextLine` with the `canvas.nativeCanvas.drawTextLine()` function:

```kotlin
val textLine = TextLine.make(yourTextString, yourFont)
val xOffset = when (yourTextAlign) {
    // There are probably better ways to handle Start, End, and Justify...
    TextAlign.Left, TextAlign.Start -> 0f
    TextAlign.Right, TextAlign.End -> textLine.width
    TextAlign.Center, TextAlign.Justify -> textLine.width / 2f
}
val actualX = x - xOffset

canvas.nativeCanvas.drawTextLine(textLine, actualX, y, yourPaint)
```

Comment: Same in Desktop Compose `1.0.0-alpha3`

Comment: Thanks for this. One more caveat: the computation of `xOffset` for `TextAlign.Start` and `TextAlign.End` should be reversed in a right-to-left layout.